# Jquery Ajax call to WCF ajax enabled web service not working on Firefox

Tags: wcf, jquery, jquery-widgets

I have created a WCF ajax enabled web service named "Service1.svc"
  "I have to call this Service In another app's using Jquery."
  I have created on method in it  :

```
    [OperationContract]             
    public string GetMarkup()
    {   
       string data = "<div>My HTML markup text here</div>";
       return data;
    }
```

Now I have created jquery script in my second application's html page :

```
var markup = "";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:1676/MyWCFService.svc/GetMarkup",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: callback,        
    error: function (textStatus) {
        alert("ERROR");
    }
});
function callback(result) {
    alert("Inside Callback");
    markup = result.d;
    $("#divMyMarkup").html(markup);
    alert(markup);
}
```

NOW, My Problem is that Whenever I execute this page in IE its working fine.
   But In Firefox its not working. It giving alert Error Message which defined in 
`error: function (textStatus) {alert("ERROR");}` in above ajax call.

I tried this functionality using $.get(), $("#divMyMarkup").load(serviceUrl, callback).
I also tried this by changing the datatype as json, jsonp, html .
Still I am not getting the exact solution.

Any Expert here?

Comment: Why not alert the textstatus param in the error callback rather than a string. The contents of textstatus may help you, also have you used fiddler to see if the xhr call is actually made? Does it respond with a status of 200? Is your page served with the same url and port? Are you falling foul of the same origin policy?

Comment: when the get request it giving "405 Method Not Allowed localhost:1676" in firefox and error : undefined in alert message.

Comment: Sounds like you're making a cross-domain call to me.  You said 'my second application' is where you're making the ajax call.  Just changing the data type to `jsonp` isn't going to make it work.  Are you making a cross-domain call here?

Comment: yes david.. I tried with jsonp...
One more interesting thing is that when I keep the contenttype : "text/plain", the service hit from IE and Firefox both.
But in firefox response is empty and get service is 200 OK.

Comment: You cannot do this cross domain. You can use jsonp but you will need to change your service to return the json wrapped in the callback function see http://jasonkelly.net/2009/05/using-jquery-jsonp-for-cross-domain-ajax-with-wcf-services/

Answer (score 3):

> In another app's using Jquery

In my experience, IE won't respect the cross-domain policy and let you do the call, not a reference...

The only way to find out is to have your html page/JQuery script calling your WCF service from `http://localhost:1676/ICallWcfServicesWithJQuery.html` on Firefox.

Possible solutions:

- **[JSONP]** [how to avoid cross domain policy in jquery ajax for consuming wcf service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686059/how-to-avoid-cross-domain-policy-in-jquery-ajax-for-consuming-wcf-service)
- **[flXHR][php-proxy]** [jQuery “getJSON” from an external domain that doesn't support JSON-P output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845715/jquery-getjson-from-an-external-domain-that-doesnt-support-json-p-output)
- **[JSONP]** [Accessing web Service from jQuery - cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697557/accessing-web-service-from-jquery-cross-domain)
- **[.net-proxy]** [aspnet-proxy-page-cross-domain-requests-from-ajax-and-javascript](http://www.johnchapman.name/aspnet-proxy-page-cross-domain-requests-from-ajax-and-javascript/)

Test on multiple browsers, add 1oz of gin, a can of tonic and you'll be good!